# format varchar to datetime SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which one of the columns is varchar but stores datetime.

Instead of saving date as varchar I am creating a new column. To copy existing date I use

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime,entryTime,101)
```

The original date is `'7/13/2015 2:40:44 AM'`

After using convert function I get

`'2015-07-13 02:40:44.000'`

What should I use to format it, to look like the original?

Comment: I did not find on google so I posted here :)...using 103 gives me an error...the conversion of varchar to datetime resulted in an out-of-range

Comment: @Veljko89 - your query will throw error - **The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

Comment: if below example works for you then marked as an answer if not then provide comments on it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of using cast, use convert like you tried but if the date format is wrong then try using a different region.

I use [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/robyn-pages-sql-server-datetime-workbench/) excellent post on date/times, have a read and it should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME='7/13/2015 2:40:44 AM' --Original Date
DECLARE @UpdateDate AS DATETIME=''
SELECT @UpdateDate = CONVERT(DATETIME ,@Date ,101)  --Converted Date
--SELECT @UpdateDate 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ,@UpdateDate ,101) +' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8) ,@UpdateDate ,108) ExpectedDate --As per your expected result.
```

With AM/PM try below,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ,@UpdateDate ,101)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8) ,@UpdateDate ,108) 
      +' '+RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30) ,@UpdateDate ,9) ,2) ExpectedDate --As per your expected result with AM/PM
```